# UserScript first steps

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

Im doing my first userscript and i'm having some issues, basically I just want to speed up a video when pressing some button.

```
    $("video").addClass('speed');
    document.getElementsByClassName('speed')[0].id='speed'
    document.getElementById("speed").playbackRate = 2
```

When I do this in my console it works but when I do this from my script i get `Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

Also, I dont know why but to get this working even from the console I need to inspect the  element otherwise it will do just as the script and wont add my className.

Do you have some tips for me ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Have you checked what `document.getElementsByClassName('speed')` returns?

Comment: An empty array, as I said I dont know why but when I do $("video").addClass('speed'); without inspecting the <video> element i does not add the class name

It seems that when I inspect the element it changes my javascript context. How can I do this manually ?

Comment: Why do you get your element by the newly added class? Try  `$("video").addClass('speed');
$("video").id='speed';
$("video").playbackRate = 2;`